# Emacs - How to change kill to delete?

Tags: emacs, edit

I only want <kbd>C-w</kbd> and <kbd>M-w</kbd> to modify the kill-ring, along with the system's clipboard [<kbd>C-c</kbd> (copy), <kbd>C-x</kbd> (cut)].

I use <kbd>M-d</kbd> and <kbd>M-DEL</kbd> often, but I do not want to yank and then cycle through <kbd>M-y</kbd> every time.

I was looking at [the emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Erasing.html#Erasing) but it does not answer my question.

Example: I want to bind <kbd>M-d</kbd> "kill-word" to "delete-word", but "delete-word" does not exist. How do I make it so? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See Emacs Wiki, page [BackwardDeleteWord](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackwardDeleteWord).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From EmacsWiki
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackwardDeleteWord

```
(defun delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters forward until encountering the end of a word.
With argument, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (delete-region (point) (progn (forward-word arg) (point)))))

(defun backward-delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters backward until encountering the end of a word.
With argument, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-word (- arg)))

(global-set-key (read-kbd-macro "<M-DEL>") 'backward-delete-word)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `delete-region` instead of `kill-region` so the text isn't saved in the kill-ring, eg. something along the lines of

```
(defun my-delete-word (start)
  (interactive "d")
  (backward-word)
  (delete-region (point) start))
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a macro to change any kill command into a delete command.

```
(defmacro delete-instead-of-kill (&rest body)
  "Replaces `kill-region' with `delete-region' in BODY."
  `(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'kill-region)
              (lambda (beg end &optional region)
                ;; FIXME: account for region arg
                (delete-region beg end))))
     ,@body))

(defun delete-word (&optional arg)
  "Like `kill-word', but deletes instead of killing."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-instead-of-kill (kill-word arg)))
```

I use a similar macro for copying.

```
(defmacro copy-instead-of-kill (&rest body)
  "Replaces `kill-region' with `kill-ring-save' in BODY."
  `(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'kill-region)
              (lambda (beg end &optional region)
                (kill-ring-save beg end region)
                (setq this-command 'kill-region))))
     ,@body))
```

Comment: Who downvoted this? What's not good about this? Is it because of the Fixme? Can I implement it anyway?

Comment: The FIXME refers to the fact that `kill-region` has 3 args, while `delete-region` has only 2.  The extra arg makes `kill-region` ignore the region specified in the args and use the current region instead.  I haven't bothered to account for this, so it's not a perfect replacement.  I've never had trouble though.

Comment: And to be clear, the `region` arg isn't used in `kill-word`, so `delete-instead-of-kill` will make an equivalent `delete-word`.

Comment: Ok. I did implement it and it works perfectly. I'm no pro but it seems like an elegant solution to me. I still don't understand the downvote.